# Facebook Insights api to my web app

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I am having trouble figuring out how to get Facebook insights into from my business page into a dashboard of a small web app I build.

I have tried the facebook docs and searched for tutorials. What I do find I cant seem to get working.

Could anyone help with some code that I could past into my page to get me started.

Something like the breakdown of female and male visitors for last month.

https://graph.facebook.com/100001972416707/insights/page_impressions_by_city_unique/week/?access_token=QWERTYUI&since=1315699200&until=1320796800

I have tried the above link for my page but I get the error

{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid OAuth access token.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}

Not sure where to get the access_token, I got one from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/ but it did not work also.

I would be grateful if someone can put me on the right path, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to request the access_token via the OAuth process: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: thanks for that, a good starting point, this was what I was missing